# Check if block is still in the world after delay

Tags: java, bukkit

I want to check if a block that's placed is still there after a short delay and execute a command

I have tried with sleep but it just gives the block that was there before the delay

```
public class BlockListener implements Listener {
    @EventHandler
    public void check(BlockPlaceEvent e)
    {          
      Material blockType = e.getBlockPlaced().getType();
      int locationX = e.getBlockPlaced().getLocation().getBlockX();
      int locationY = e.getBlockPlaced().getLocation().getBlockY();
      int locationZ = e.getBlockPlaced().getLocation().getBlockZ();
      String locationXb = String.valueOf(locationX);
      String locationYb = String.valueOf(locationY);
      String locationZb = String.valueOf(locationZ);
      World world = e.getPlayer().getWorld();          
      if ((blockType == Material.PLAYER_HEAD) || (blockType == Material.PLAYER_WALL_HEAD))
        {
          try
          {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
          }
          catch (InterruptedException ex)
          {
            
          }
          Material block = world.getBlockAt(locationX, locationY, locationZ).getType();
          if((block == Material.PLAYER_WALL_HEAD) || (block == Material.PLAYER_HEAD)){
             //empty
          }
          else {
            Bukkit.dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), command);
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should **NEVER** use the `Thread.sleep` method on spigot. It stop the all server.

You need to use Scheduler ([Tutorial](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/scheduler-programming/) - Javadoc: [`BukkitScheduler`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/scheduler/BukkitScheduler.html)) :

```java
@EventHandler
public void check(BlockPlaceEvent e) {
  Material blockType = e.getBlockPlaced().getType();
  int locationX = e.getBlockPlaced().getLocation().getBlockX();
  int locationY = e.getBlockPlaced().getLocation().getBlockY();
  int locationZ = e.getBlockPlaced().getLocation().getBlockZ();
  String locationXb = String.valueOf(locationX);
  String locationYb = String.valueOf(locationY);
  String locationZb = String.valueOf(locationZ);
  World world = e.getPlayer().getWorld();
  if ((blockType == Material.PLAYER_HEAD) || (blockType == Material.PLAYER_WALL_HEAD)) {
    Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater(MyPlugin.getInstance(), () -> {
      Material block = world.getBlockAt(locationX, locationY, locationZ).getType();
      if ((block == Material.PLAYER_WALL_HEAD) || (block == Material.PLAYER_HEAD)) {
        //empty
      } else {
        Bukkit.dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), command);
      }
    }, 20);
  }
}
```

Where:

- `MyPlugin.getInstance()` is to get the instance of your JavaPlugin, it's also mostly called as `plugin` variable.
- `() -> {}` is what will be run
- `20` is the time (in ticks) that the server should wait. 20 ticks = 1 second.